# Grouping list of integers in a range into chunks

Tags: python

Given a set or a list (assume its ordered)

```
myset = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

I want to find out how many numbers appear in a range. 
say my range is 10. Then given the list above, I have two sets of 10.

I want the function to return `[10,10]`

if my range was 15. Then I should get `[15,5]`

The range will change. Here is what I came up with

```
myRange = 10
start = 1
current = start
next = current + myRange
count = 0
setTotal = []
for i in myset:
    if i >= current and i < next :
        count = count + 1
        print str(i)+" in "+str(len(setTotal)+1)
    else:
        current = current + myRange
        next = myRange + current
        if next >= myset[-1]:
            next = myset[-1]
        setTotal.append(count)
        count = 0

print setTotal
```

Output

```
1 in 1
2 in 1
3 in 1
4 in 1
5 in 1
6 in 1
7 in 1
8 in 1
9 in 1
10 in 1
12 in 2
13 in 2
14 in 2
15 in 2
16 in 2
17 in 2
18 in 2
19 in 2
[10, 8]
```

notice 11 and 20 where skipped. I also played around with the condition and got wired results.

EDIT: Range defines a range that every value in the range should be counted into one chuck.

think of a range as from current value to currentvalue+range as one chunk.

EDIT:

Wanted output:

```
1 in 1
2 in 1
3 in 1
4 in 1
5 in 1
6 in 1
7 in 1
8 in 1
9 in 1
10 in 1
11 in 2
12 in 2
13 in 2
14 in 2
15 in 2
16 in 2
17 in 2
18 in 2
19 in 2
[10, 10]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what a "range" is?

Comment: Can you please explain the logic behind the "range" better?

Comment: I tried. In the edit above.

Comment: That is a chunk size, not a range. Python has a `range()` function, which has a start, an end and a stride.

Comment: my chunk size should be able to change. While the range is static. Give the range size of 15 and the set above. Notice the first chunk size is 15 but the second chunk size is 5

Comment: Yes, the other number is the remainder.

Comment: Please not the desired output I have posted after the 2nd edit.

Comment: @user1048138: Why is `20` still missing from your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the right key function, the`groupby`method in the `itertools`module makes doing this fairly simple:

```
from itertools import groupby

def ranger(values, range_size):
    def keyfunc(n):
        key = n/(range_size+1) + 1
        print '{} in {}'.format(n, key)
        return key

    return [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(values, key=keyfunc)]

myset = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
print ranger(myset, 10)
print ranger(myset, 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use simple division and the remainder; the [`divmod()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) gives you both:

```
def chunks(lst, size):
    count, remainder = divmod(len(lst), size)
    return [size] * count + ([remainder] if remainder else [])
```

To create your desired output, then use the output of `chunks()`:

```
lst = range(1, 21)
size = 10

start = 0
for count, chunk in enumerate(chunks(lst, size), 1):
    for i in lst[start:start + chunk]:
        print '{} in {}'.format(i, count)
    start += chunk
```

`count` is the number of the current chunk (starting at 1; python uses 0-based indexing normally).

This prints:

```
1 in 1
2 in 1
3 in 1
4 in 1
5 in 1
6 in 1
7 in 1
8 in 1
9 in 1
10 in 1
11 in 2
12 in 2
13 in 2
14 in 2
15 in 2
16 in 2
17 in 2
18 in 2
19 in 2
20 in 2
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care about what numbers are in a given chunk, you can calculate the size easily:

```
def chunk_sizes(lst, size):
    complete = len(lst) // size  # Number of `size`-sized chunks
    partial = len(lst) % size    # Last chunk

    if partial:  # Sometimes the last chunk is empty
        return [size] * complete + [partial]
    else:
        return [size] * complete
```

Comment: what is size, I dont care about size. I want numbers between (n, m) to be split into a chuck where n is my a lower bound and m is upper bound

Comment: @user1048138: Read the code before saying that it doesn't work.

Comment: could you explain the code. I dont understand it but it works.

Comment: and sorry, I thought I was commenting on someone else's code post

Comment: so `return [size] * complete + [partial]` Thats a list * an int * an int. what is that returning. Its breaking using my larger dataset.

Comment: @user1048138: `[2] * 4 == [2, 2, 2, 2]`. How large is large?

Comment: the issue is that the list is not continues. that is it could be missing numbers. myset = [1,3,4,7,8,9,10] and size = 2 wont work